# Elastic Search query filtering

Tags: python, search, curl, elasticsearch

I have uploaded some data into Elastic server as " job id , job place , job req , job desc ". My index is my_index and doctype = job_list.

I need to write a query to find a particular term say " Data Analyst " and it should give me back matching results with a specified field like " job place " .

ie, Data Analyst term matching in the documents , and I need to have all "job place" information only.

Any help. I tried curd . but not working. if it is in python good.

Comment: Show us the code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'your_host', 'port': 9200}])

q = {"filter": 
        {"term": 
            {"job desc": "Data Analyst"}
        },
     "_source": {
            "include": ['job place']
        }
    }
# Assume you want "Data Analyst" in the "job desc" field

result = es.search(index='my_index', doc_type='job_list', body=q)
```

Comment: @user3368375 It's just a example. There're too many things can go wrong. I just write the essential part, the term filter and `_source` part. I can't tell why unless there are the index mapping and example data.

Answer (score 1):

the above search example looks correct.Try lowercasing the Data "Analyst" as "data analyst".

if doesn't help post your mappings,query you firing and response you are getting.